# does applications created with Qt Creator require end user to install a plugin?

Tags: qt-creator

seeing that applications created with QT claims to run on all platforms, windows, linux, mac....

does the end user require to run or install a plugin ?

or does the applications run natively on each platform....does the end user just install my software and able to run my application fine ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end user doesn't need to install a plug-in.

He needs a copy of the qt-library. You can either distribute it as a shared library or you can statically compile it into the application. If you opt for the shared library you can let your installer install that.

You have to compile a binary for each platform you want to deploy your application on. That means you cannot distribute the same application for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile statically your application. This way You will not have to distribute qt so/dlls with executable file.

But Georg is right, it is enough that You provide qt dlls with your executable file. At least on windows. In linux environment usually qt is provided as part of environment. So your application would have to depend on certain libraries provided with the operating system.